# html accessibility: anchor tags with background images on pseudo elements

Tags: html, image, background, accessibility

My company is exploring some scenarios that we use commonly in our design that we are realizing may not be 100% compliant with WCAG 2.0 standards.

One such scenario is that we have anchor tags (social media links, for example) that have no content and a background image declared on a pseudo element.

The best alternatives I'm aware of are:

1. Use a `title` attribute on the link
2. Add text to the link wrapped in a `span` with a "screen reader only" class, such as this example from [eBay Mind Patterns](https://ebay.gitbooks.io/mindpatterns/content/techniques/offscreentext.html):

   ```
   .clipped {
     border: 0 !important;
     clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
     clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
     height: 1px !important;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 0 !important;
     position: absolute !important;
     white-space: nowrap !important;
     width: 1px !important;
   }
   ```

And to be explicit, this is an example of the pseudo class background image styling we're using

```
.pseudo::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background-image: url('images/pizza.png');
}
```

Any ideas which of these is more compliant?

**Option 1: Title, no text inside**

```
<a title="pizza title" href="http://pizza.com" class="pseudo pizza"></a>
```

**Option 2: screen reader only text in the link**

```
<a href="http://pizza.com" class="pseudo pizza">
    <span class="clipped">pizza text</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: prefer the second one, if possible.

The `title` attribute is a bit tricky since not all screen readers read it by default. So to be on the safe side and 100% covered by screen readers, use the text inside the `<a>` tags and make it screen reader-only, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I also would vote for the second option, but another method is to actually have text content in the link, but add `text-indent: -5000px;` (or another similarly high negative value)  to its CSS to move the text off the screen.

Comment: Thank you for the input.  Are there advantages to the `text-indent` methodology other than removing the `span` tag?

Comment: I am not sure, maybe browser compatability, but as I said: not sure. I just wanted to mention this additional method, which in my experience works well.

Comment: Don't use text-indent: -9999px; it seems that text far away from the actual screen slows down VoiceOver on iOS and mac, and the more off-scrren it is, the more slow down I observe.

Answer (score 0):

When it's hard to chose between the best of two worlds, do not try to.

Easiest solution :

```
<a href="http://pizza.com" class="pseudo pizza" title="pizza text" aria-label="pizza test">
    <span class="clipped">pizza text</span>
</a>
```

Why? Because the `title` attribute will be accessible to non screenreader users as a tooltip, and a screenreader may use the clipped text when it's not configured to use it.

The use of `aria-label` is also very important as using CSS for visually hiding elements may result in random behavior depending on the assistive technology used. For instance, some assistive technologies may chose to remove non visible text while others keep them.

The best choice for supporting all screenreaders is to use the three options : `aria-label` for recent screenreaders, clipped text for old ones, and `title` attribute for standard users.

Comment: In my limited experience with screen readers (specifically NVDA), including text and a title can often result in duplicated text.  I am inclined to not include all three of these because in the most extreme scenario, it would result in someone hearing the same text three times, which is not an improvement in my opinion.  Do you have examples of any assistive technologies that would choose not to read text in a `.clipped` class like the one in the OP?  My understanding is that `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` are bad, but styling the text as "hard to see" rather than invisible is OK.

Comment: @EricDauenhauer A standard browser does not display the clipped text, and it won't be a solution for 99% of the users. While browser, accessibility plugins or custom CSS/scripts may display the `aria-label` or the `title` attribute, it's impossible for them to expose visually something that has been done voluntarily to be hidden. This is an accessibility problem for deaf people with low vision (old people for instance). The text alternative computation algorithm defines that `aria-label` is the first thing to be used and `title` the last one (but the only one who can benefit to standard users)